# Unit testing a controller - in need of a second pair of eyes

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

Hello I need help writing a test for this controller function. I think I am close but I keep getting Expected undefined to equal { entityId : 2, page : 19, length : 200 }. This seems odd though since I have another test that is almost identical. If anyone can spot the error or has any general testing advice I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

```
   $scope.getAll = function (page, length) {

        accountService.getAccounts(global.activeOrganizationId, page, length).then(function (data) {
            $scope.accounts = data;
        });

    };
```

This is what I have so far

```
describe('AccountsController', function () {
    //make module avalible to tests
    beforeEach(module('pb.accounts.controllers'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
    beforeEach(module('ui.bootstrap'));

    var $controller;
    var mockGlobal = { activeOrganizationId: 0 };
    var mockStateParams = { orgId: 1, entityId: null };
    var mockForm = {};

    var mockAccountSrv = {
        account: {
            entityId: 2,
            page: 19,
            length: 200
        }
    };

    // instantiating controller
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_) {
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

describe("getAll() function", function() {
        var controller, scope;


        beforeEach(inject(function ($q) {
            mockAccountSrv.getAccounts = function (entityId, page, length) {
                var defer = $q.defer();
                defer.resolve(this.account);
                return defer.promise;
            };
        }));

        // sets scope of controller before each test
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('AccountsController',
                {
                    $scope: scope,
                    $stateParams: mockStateParams,
                    global: mockGlobal,
                    accountService: mockAccountSrv
                });
        }));

        it("make sure service promise resolves", function () {
            scope.getAll(mockAccountSrv.account.page, mockAccountSrv.account.length);
            scope.$digest();

            expect(scope.account).toEqual(mockAccountSrv.account);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Could it be that you are testing the `scope.account` while the data gets to `$scope.accounts` (final "s")?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering I made a silly typo using mockAccountSrv.account instead of .accounts 
Thanks for looking though! and thanks Nikos